# Show Python variables as children of function in Tagbar (gVim, with exuberant ctags)

Tags: python, vim, ctags, tagbar

I am trying to show variables inside functions in Tagbar for gVim. Currently, functions are shown inside classes, and variables are shown inside classes, but variables are not shown inside functions. I would like to be able to see which variables are used inside each function.

I have tried messing around with 'kind2scope' and 'scope2kind' in Tagbar, to no avail. I think this may require editing both Tagbar and ctags, but I could be [am probably] completely wrong.

I am new to Python, and as such, the code is probably pretty nasty.

This is what Tagbar currently looks like:

[gVim Tagbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxMur.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a (maybe intentional) limitation of Exuberant Ctags to not show local variables in any language. If that got implemented in ctags it would be trivial to adjust Tagbar to make use of it -- depending on the exact implementation Tagbar would potentially not need any changes at all. But it would definitely need support in ctags in order to work at all.